# What defines where files will be saved?

Tags: arcpy, layers, workspace

I have a script I am using to save out layers automatically and would like some help with understanding where my files are being saved out to.

In my current code, the file that I am processing is being picked up in the arcpy.env.workspace.

But the layers that I am saving out are being saved in the same place. How do change where the files are being saved ?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

#Variables which need to pick for this are the attribute that you are going to   filter the layers on

# This is where the file is being picked up from 
arcpy.env.workspace = "U:\\Script\\layers_Files\\"
# The file to be processed 
Source_File = "feilds_template.shp"

Company_Bulk_Company_List = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor   (Source_File,"HC_TYPE")]
UniqueCompany = set(Company_Bulk_Company_List)
print UniqueCompany

 # Getting the list out 
 for company_query in UniqueCompany:

 #env.workspace = "S:\\AppsData\\GIS\\PROJECT\\COMPANIES\\SHAPEFILES\\"

    out_layer0 = str(company_query)+"lyr"
    in_layer = out_layer0
    out_layer = in_layer +"lyr"

 #MakeFeatureLayer variables
    in_features = "IHS_FEILDS_AREAS.shp"

    where_clause = '"HC_TYPE" = ' + "'" + company_query + "'"
    print where_clause
    workspace = " U:\\Script\\layers_Files\\"

    try:
    # Execute MakeFeatureLayer
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features, out_layer0, where_clause, workspace)

    # Execute SaveToLayerFile
         arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(in_layer, out_layer, "ABSOLUTE")
    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: My noob guess is `workspace = " U:\\Script\\layers_Files\\"`, before your `try` statement. I don't use Arc but your first algorithm "Execute MakeFeatureLayer" looks like it's outputting the results in the `workspace` location. This is just a guess =)

Comment: I have tried changing the above the try statement , but little saves out the files in the arcpy.env.workspace , where the file is picked up

Comment: Hopefully others can help advise you on this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the value of out_layer to include the output path. Add `import os` to the start of your script and then set the out_layer variable as follows:

```
out_layer = os.path.join("your/output/path/here", in_layer + "lyr")
```

Comment: This does save out the first layer into the folder. But it is only saving 1 layer . Previously it would save all layers automatically